# sqlite3: Intersect two tables where one value BETWEEN two others

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables, one has single entries like this:

```
'rs47' 1027
```

The other has ranges:

```
'gene1' 1000 1500
```

These tables are *huge*, so I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to get all entries from table 1 where the entries are within any range in table 2.

I don't think that INTERSECT can be used like this. I know how to use SELECT to do this for a single entry:

```
SELECT name FROM 'table2' INDEXED BY 'start_end' WHERE 1027 BETWEEN start AND end
```

But I am not sure how to do that for **every** record in a table. Any ideas?

Comment: Does "single entries" mean "entire rows" or "a value in one column"?

Comment: @CL It means value in one column. I want to compare a single position in one column to a range of positions in another table. I did this last night using python to iterate through all 200 million rows and compare them to a dictionary or ranges. Unsurprisingly it took about 12 hours to run. I feel like it should be much faster with sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether corresponding rows exist in the other table, you can use a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table2
              WHERE Table1.Value BETWEEN Table2.StartValue AND Table2.EndValue);
```